# Maximizing $7x+12y$ over the set $2x^2+6xy+9y^2-2x-6y\le 24$

Tags: optimization

By bounding the function, I need to find the maximum point of $7x+12y$ over the set $2x^2+6xy+9y^2-2x-6y\le 24$ (i.e., no Lagrange multipliers are allowed, etc.).

I am trying to show that $(7x+12y)^2\le C$ for a constant $C$. Then I will search for a point $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $7x_0+12y_0=\sqrt C$.

I did show that $(7x+12y)^2\le2944+18x^2+72xy$, but now I am stuck with $18x^2+72xy$.

Does anyone have some bright ideas? I am really stuck.

Comment: $7x+12y$ has constant gradient $(7,12)$. So, just keep swimming in that direction: $\max(t)$ such that $(7t,12t)$ satisfies the inequality.

Comment: @jyre The constraint is a shifted ellipse (not centered at the origin). Why is it going along the line through the origin makes the max at the intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: complete the squares in the inequality to get $x^2+(3y+x-1)^2\le 25$, then change $y$ to $z=3y+x-1$ to maximize $3x+4z$ subject to $x^2+z^2\le 25$. Now the method in the comment @jyre works. Otherwise a parameterization of the circle and maximizing $3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta$ works as well.

Comment: Of course an ellipse is transformed into a circle under a change of coordinates and a linear map stays linear under this transformation. Tank you.

Answer (score 1):

Inequality. Lagrange multiplier excluded.

$2x^2+6xy+9y^2-2x-6y\le 24$

$\implies x^2+(x+3y)-2x-6y^\le 24$

let $z=x+3y$, we have:

$x^2+z^2-2z\le24$

$\implies x^2+(z-1)^2\le25,$

which is a circle. And the function whose value is to maximized can be transformed to:

$7x+12y=7x+12\cdot\cfrac{z-x}{3}=3x+4z$,

let $c=3x+4z$, we have $z=\cfrac{-3x+c}{4}$, this is a line in xz plane with slope $-\cfrac 34$, and we want to maximize the y axis of the points of all lines with the given slope and intersect(or touch) to cirle. From the geometric interpretation of the problem, we know that the line pass the point on top-right  of the circle with direvative of -0.75. the value of $c$ associate with it, the maximum value required, can be arrived at accordingly.